# Salesforce System Error when accessing a list in @AuraEnabled method

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, bug, gack, aura-attribute

My Lightning Component controller:

```
doActivateNext : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.activateNext");
    action.setParams({ bpiId : component.get("v.recordId"), 
                       stages : component.get("v.stages") });
    ...
}
```

calls this `@AuraEnabled` Apex method:

```
public static void activateNext(Id bpiId, List<BpiStage> stageList) {
    System.debug(stageList); // I see a non-empty list in the logs

    for(BpiStage stage : stageList) {
        System.debug(stage); // Fails before outputt
    }
}
```

The `System.debug()` in line 3 perfectly prints a list of objects of the `BpiStage` class. But as soon stages is access in the `for` loop (or any other method like `.isEmpty()` or `.get(0)` or `[0]`) the code fails with a:

> 11:55:45:030 FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System
>   Error: 1261878509-48218 (152924272) (152924272)

What is going on here?

Comment: Looks weird, can you try passing the list as JSON string and deserialize it in controller?

Comment: I expected Lightning to do that for me...How would I do that? I am Lightning newbie ;-)

Comment: Is the problem a mismatch in types where stages is a `list<BpiStage>` and the loop is iterating over a `list<BpiChevronStage>`? I'm surprised the Apex compiler would have even allowed that in the first place.

Comment: @martin: No this was just a copy and past error inside of Stackexchange... Corrected it.

Comment: Convert the array to string using JSON.stringify. So `stages : JSON.stringify(component.get("v.stages"))`. Try deserializing the string to `List< BpiStage>` in the controller.

Comment: @Praveen: Can you add that as answer. I think you got it. I think this is a platform bug.

Comment: @RobertSösemann I have added the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks weird,might be a bug. As a workaround, try passing the `stages` array as string from the component and deserialize the string to `List<BpiStage>` in the apex controller.

**Controller.js**

```
ction.setParams({ bpiId : component.get("v.recordId"), 
                  stages : JSON.stringify(component.get("v.stages")) });
```

**AuraMethod:**

```
public static void activateNext(Id bpiId, String stageStr) {
    List<BpiStage> stageList = (List<BpiStage>)JSON.deserialize(stageStr,List<BpiStage>.class)
    System.debug(stageList);

    for(BpiStage stage : stageList) {
        System.debug(stage);
    }
}
```

Comment: The same workaround was proposed by Salesforce Support in Case 14941232. I asked them to file a Know Issue for it so we can keep track.

Comment: There is no Know Issue for that yet but you can log a ticket with salesforce mentioning the same Bug number - W-3159538 to know the status.